Sum of $n$ weighted dice rolls is divisible by $3$.
A dice with sides $0, 1, 2$ each with weighted probabilities $\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}$ respectively is rolled $n$ times. What is the probability that the total is divisible by $3$?
I've already solved the problem using a recurrence relation. If my work is correct, denoting $a_n$ to be the probability that after $n$ rolls the total is $0 \text{ mod } 3$, we have
$$a_n= \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot2^{n-1}}$$
I'm looking for an alternative (combinatorial would be preferred) method to solve this problem, because the simplicity of the answer suggests that there should be an elegant way to reach it. (Also, the problem itself is from a worksheet intended for year 12 high school students, doing it with linear algebra must be overkill, I am definitely missing something)

For completion's sake, here is the way I arrived at $a_n$. Let $b_n$ and $c_n$ be the probabilities of the total being $1,2 \text{ mod } 3$ respectively after $n$ rolls. Then,
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=\frac{2}{3}a_n+\frac{1}{6}b_n+\frac{1}{6}c_n\\
b_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{6}a_n+\frac{2}{3}b_n+\frac{1}{6}c_n\\
c_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{6}a_n+\frac{1}{6}b_n+\frac{2}{3}c_n
\end{align}
With initial conditions $a_1=\frac{2}{3}, b_1=c_1=\frac{1}{6}$. Since the recurrences for $b_n$ and $c_n$ are symmetrical, we have $b_n=c_n$, so we are solving
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=\frac{2}{3}a_n+\frac{1}{3}b_n\\
b_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{6}a_n+\frac{5}{6}b_n\\
\end{align}
Which is
$$\left[\matrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}}\right] = \left[\matrix{\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6}}\right] \left[\matrix{a_n\\b_n}\right]=\left[\matrix{1& -2\\1 & 1}\right] \left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{2}}\right] \left[\matrix{1& -2\\1 & 1}\right]^{-1} \left[\matrix{a_n\\b_n}\right]\\
=\left[\matrix{1& -2\\1 & 1}\right] \left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & \frac{1}{2^n}}\right] \left[\matrix{1& -2\\1 & 1}\right]^{-1} \left[\matrix{a_1\\b_1}\right]$$
And then proceed with substitution and expansion.

This is my first question on MSE, let me know if I could have done anything better! Thanks for the help.

One approach is to turn it into a linear recurrence in one variable. Conditioning on the value after $(n-1)$ steps, you can obtain
$$
a_n = \frac23 a_{n-1} + \frac16 (1-a_{n-1}).
$$
(You can also obtain this from your system of recurrences by noting that $a_n=1-b_n-c_n=1-2b_n$.)
Rearranging, you get
$$
a_n-\frac13 = \frac12\left(a_{n-1}-\frac13\right).
$$
In this form you can immediately see (by induction) that $a_n-\frac13 = (1/2)^n\left(a_0-\frac13\right)$, which leads to your formula.

I totally forgot that they have to sum to $1$... oops.
